# sp324099: could not complete the operation. VS 2015 CE

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed VS 2015 CE on my machine. But now its 30 days trial version has been expired and I have to update my license by sign in with my Microsoft account.

When I try to sign in I get this error: "SP324099: Could not complete the operation."

I searched on internet to find out the solution for this problem and found that most of the times that solution worked for this problem is to upgrade your IE8 browser to IE 11. But my machine has IE8 installed and I can't update IE to IE 11 because of dependency of some of my application with IE 8.

Is there any solution to resolve this issue without upgrading to IE 11 ? Please suggest.

I really appreciate you to help me with this problem.